# how to use the same object on different classes in python?

Tags: python, oop, class

This is probably a very basic question.

I have some objects that I want to be created once and then used by many classes of my application, for instance "logging" and "db". I don't wanna make a new connection to the DB everytime a different class wants to do something.

So my idea was to create a Class like:

```
class MyDB(object):
    mydb=createMySQLconnection()
```

then I'd do "from ... import MyDB" and use MyDB.mydb

would it work? is this the best way to do that?

Comment: I would pass the connection in as a parameter to each classes' `__init__()`. Or, if you don't plan on only using this connection throughout the program, you can inherit all of you classes from `MyDB`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This would work, but there's no reason to create a class. Just put `mydb` in a module as a free-standing variable.

Often, when you'd use a [singleton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) in other programming languages, you can get by in Python with a module.